# Why there is a wye under a pedestal?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drainage, drain-waste-vent, p-trap

Is there a reason why the builder used a wye under the pedestal with one end capped with a mechanical cap.

The P-Trap is located under the floor.

I’m replacing the pedestal with a vanity.
Do I need this wye for the drainage?

[image]

Comment: cleanout access

Comment: As the original owner of the house, I never used this access in 10 years. Another newly built house for a friend of mine has the same exact setup.  Why not using the P-Trap clean-out plug instead? Does it have to do anything with the drainage vent mechanism?

Comment: The P-trap clean out is usually on the bottom.  It leaks/lets wet stuff out when it it is opened up.  The wye clean out is nice and neat(until you start pulling stuff out).

Comment: @jsotola - answers, even ones that the robots think are terribly short, (but in this case correct, even if you do need to add a filler word or three before it will take it) go below...

Comment: @Henry You stated that the trap is under the floor. That makes accessing the cleanout plug on it rather inconvenient. It may also be a local code requirement as you mention the same on a newly built house in the area. Trap under the floor for a normal height sink is generally too far below it to be code-legal under the codes I work with.

Comment: The P-Trap is  accessible from the basement.

Comment: @Ecnerwal this is a duplicate of so many other similar questions

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the idea that the wye allows for a cleanout access there may be another reason that this fitting was used.

The original installer may have found that the shown combination of fittings was the best way for them to adapt from the location of the pipe coming up from the floor to the necessary offset needed to properly engage the drain location on the sink that sits upon the pedestal.